# Access VBA Loop (Not Responding)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looping through a recordset to carry out some basic functions or edits.

Usually with recordsets with more than 50 records, access will stop responding.

I have `me.repaint` before the loop command but the window always freezes and the access title bar shows: ...(Not Responding).

Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks.

Dave.

**EDIT: Added Loop Code**

```
If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.Guardians_Subform1.Form.Recordset

Dim strFirstName, strLastName As String

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst 

    Do Until rs.EOF = True     
rs.Edit
    strFirstName = Trim(StrConv(rs!FirstName, 3))
    strLastName = Trim(StrConv(rs!LastName, 3))
    If rs!FirstName <> strFirstName Then
    rs!FirstName = strFirstName
    End If

    If rs!LastName <> strLastName Then
    rs!LastName = strLastName
    End If

     rs.Update
       rs.MoveNext
Me.Repaint
    Loop  
Else
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset."
End If
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Dave could you provide the code for this please. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Also, access should be able to handle recordsets up to [1gig](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854) in size. How big are your records?

Comment: The last recordset had less than 100 records. I've added the loop code. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just run a single update statement to trim the field values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the [DoEvents-Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264522.aspx) within the loop to pass control to the operating system to redraw your Access-GUI and to process any other Window-Messages that might need processing. By that the application will not be marked as "Not responding" in the Task Manager and the Title Bar.

```
Do Until rs.EOF = True
  [...]
  rs.MoveNext
  DoEvents
Loop
```

There is a small performance trade off. If not calling DoEvents, the total execution time for the loop will be a little shorter, but Access will do nothing else then process your loop. Therefore it seems to be not responding.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out you can use the DoEvents to release your processor to do other actions before continuing. When I use the DoEvents in a loop I use a counter.

```
Dim iCounter as Integer

Do Until
' some code here
   iCounter=iCounter+1
   If iCounter = 100 then
      DoEvents
      iCounter=0
   End if
Loop
```

This keeps the DoEvents from firing too often and causing your overall code to slow. Adjust the counter to whatever iteration you find appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the best approach to do such edits with a recordset loop. An UPDATE query is much more efficient.

e.g.

```sql
UPDATE tblGuardians
SET FirstName = Trim(StrConv(FirstName, 3))
WHERE StrComp(FirstName, Trim(StrConv(FirstName, 3)), 0) <> 0
```

and the same for `LastName`.

This uses `StrComp` instead of a simple `<>` comparison, because the latter is case-insensitive. The third parameter `0` = `vbBinaryCompare`.

Comment: I do agree, a single SQL statement is usually much better than looping through a recordset for editing multiple records. - But this answer does not address the general issue of Access freezing while processing a loop.

Comment: Thanks! So I should be doing something like: DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tblGuardians SET Firstname = FirstName = Trim(StrConv(FirstName, 3)) WHERE ID =" & rs![ID] & ";"

Comment: @DaveB: No, this query doesn't run in the recordset loop, that's the point. It updates all records at once. This query (plus the one for LastName) are a **replacement** for your Loop code.